# Copy part of a char pointer to another one

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer like this:

`const u_char *packet;`

And from the 42 elements to a certain point I have to copy it in another char pointer.

```
u_char *payload = new u_char[];

int j = 0, l = 0;
while (j < header->caplen - 42 - 1) {
  if (j >= 42){
    payload[l] = packet[j];
    l++;
  }
  j++;
}
payload[l] = '\0';
```

It works fine but then at a certain packet it gives me this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x55B3FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in eval_waic.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC
```

Any idea why? It works fine til that packet! i checked, its not packet's fault..

Comment: `u_char *payload = new u_char[];` What do you think this does?

Comment: u_char *payload = new u_char[]; how large is payload here? how about u_char *payload2 = new u_char[1000];? How large is payload2?

Comment: yep sorry i have put 1000, and then I tried with 5000 as well, forgot to copy it.. but it doesnt work anyway..same error

Comment: @ayasha What is the `exact` size that you're trying to copy?  You can't just guess, somewhere it must be specified how much you must copy.  Also, sticking a 0 at the end of that array -- how do you know you haven't gone out of bounds of the allocated memory by doing that?

Comment: "...to a certain point..." - and that point would be...? Any reason you're not using a `std::vector<>` doing a little math, then a single `std:copy()` and returning the result?

Comment: [OT]: Why not initialize `j = 42`, instead of the check in the loop ?

Comment: size is 43, I am sure I am not going out of bounds. As for using std:vector<> and std:copy() I did't know it could be done and how, I will check this out.. thanks

Comment: @ayasha - `I have a pointer like this: const u_char *packet;` You did not specify how, when, and where that pointer points to valid memory.

Comment: print in the loop l and j. Also try to figure out the size of the two array. I am pretty sure you are going out of bounds.

Comment: @ayasha `I am sure I am not going out of bounds`  Then why the issue?  You can't be sure of anything if you get an access violation.  Second, (and again), why are you sticking a NULL at the end?  You could be going out of bounds (even by one byte) by doing that, and even going off by a single byte can cause memory corruption.

Comment: I'd check your caplen. knowing *nothing* about your data, and only what we see here (which ain't much), you can do this with an RAII container like `std::vector<>` easily, [this being one such way](http://pastebin.com/LuCVjFgX). If the numbers are off by one, sorry about that, but it should be clear how it works. I'm still confused why you need *any* of this. You have the packet data, you know the size, you know how deep it is. It seems all you're gaining is copying it and jamming a terminator on the end. If the caller really needs that, so be it, but it seems like a waste if they don't.

Comment: There is a bug in code you didn't show; post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `payload` enough space to store the result. From what I see

```
u_char *payload = new u_char[header->caplen - 42];
```

should do the trick.

Comment: like before :( it goes fine until packet number 65 and then it breaks down with the error before..

Comment: Why 44? With `j < header->caplen - 43` and with `payload[l] = '\0'` it should rather be `new u_char[header->caplen - 42]`.